# String Comparison with overload

Tags: c#, string

I have similar scenario in my project, I have to compare two strings, and Strings are same. But some characters are in capital letters.

```
string first = "StringCompaRison";
string second = "stringcoMparisoN";
if(first.Equals(second))
{
        Console.WriteLine("Equal ");
}
else
        Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
```

For me, output should be equal, am very new to Programming, Which overload to use? Can someone tell me the efficient way to compare?

Comment: Convert both to lowercase and compare then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of other ways to do this,
When you call a string comparison method such as String.Compare, String.Equals, or String.IndexOf, you should always call an overload that includes a parameter of type StringComparison so that you can specify the type of comparison that the method performs.

Overloads:
CurrentCulture, CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, InvariantCulture, InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, Ordinal and OrdinalIgnoreCase

For more information [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Use comparisons with StringComparison.Ordinal or StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase for better performance and as your safe default for culture-agnostic string matching,

You can use String.ToUpper, String.ToLower , but this will allocate memory for string.

This is the best way to do,

```
string first = "StringCompaRison";
string second = "stringcoMparisoN";
if(first.Equals(second,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Equal ");
}
else
        Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for this:

```
if (first.Equals(second, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

[String.Equals documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[StringComparison Enumeration documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx)

```
bool match = (String.Compare(first, second, true) == 0);
if (match)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not equal");
}
```